# How can I generate documentation for my Jersey REST API that uses JSON JAXB binding?

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jersey, jersey-1.0

Now that I've figured out [how to use JAXB generate JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18665617/can-jersey-clients-post-a-jaxb-object-to-the-server-using-json) I can request/respond with it on my server and I'd like to figure out how I can generate useful documentation for human beings that are not using Java.  My server code looks like this:

```
@POST
@Path("apath")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String postAPath(InstanceWithXmlRootElementAnnotation instanceWithXmlRootElementAnnotation) {
```

That's all well in good if someone is using Java.  I just give them the Jar with the `InstanceWithXmlRootElementAnnotation` class in it and tell them to send it over (yes, there's a little more work, ignore those details).

If they're using some other language, I don't know how I'm supposed to tell them the format of their payload and what to expect from the server if it returns a `InstanceWithXmlRootElementAnnotation`.  How can I generate documentation that explains the expected format of the JSON payload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swagger is a good option (per @fehguy) and you should also check out [enunciate](http://enunciate.codehaus.org/) and see what works best for your application...

Comment: Please note that enunciate is not compatible with java 8.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is precisely what [Swagger](http://swagger.wordnik.com) is for.  Take a look at [github](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/wiki/Java-Integrations) for details on how this integrates with JAX-RS

Answer (score 1):

Swagger uses annotations which might get you confused with other functional annotations ..

Use [APIDOC](http://apidocjs.com/) for making this nice separation between functional annotations and documentation. It looks like a normal documentation above each method.
ex:

```
/**
 * @api {get} /user/:id Request User information
 * @apiName GetUser
 * @apiGroup User
 *
 * @apiParam {Number} id Users unique ID.
 *
 * @apiSuccess {String} firstname Firstname of the User.
 * @apiSuccess {String} lastname  Lastname of the User.
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

Also try enunciate, it parses the javadoc and JAX-RS annotations of your service classes to generate documentation:

http://enunciate.codehaus.org/

Here is some example documentation generated by enunciate:

https://repository.sonatype.org/nexus-restlet1x-plugin/default/docs/index.html

There is a maven plugin that works well.It also generates client libraries in various languages as well as sample xml for xml based services. It now supports swagger documentation as well.

Comment: FYI the example documentation link is broken.