# how to send HTTP Post request using jersey with a complex parameter

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jersey-client

I need to send a HTTP Post to a REST API with the following complex type as parameters. I looked at the documentation of jersey and it helps only to send a key value pair. How can i send a HTTP Post request with the below parameters using jersey.

```
{
    "key": "example key",
    "message": {
        "html": "<p>Example HTML content</p>",
        "text": "Example text content",
        "subject": "example subject",
        "from_email": "message.from_email@example.com",
        "from_name": "Example Name",
        "to": [
            {
                "email": "recipient.email@example.com",
                "name": "Recipient Name"
            }
        ],
        "headers": {
            "Reply-To": "message.reply@example.com"
        },
        "important": false,
        "track_opens": null,
        "track_clicks": null,
        "auto_text": null,
        "auto_html": null,
        "inline_css": null,
        "url_strip_qs": null,
        "preserve_recipients": null,
        "view_content_link": null,
        "bcc_address": "message.bcc_address@example.com",
        "tracking_domain": null,
        "signing_domain": null,
        "return_path_domain": null,
        "merge": true,
        "global_merge_vars": [
            {
                "name": "merge1",
                "content": "merge1 content"
            }
        ],
        "merge_vars": [
            {
                "rcpt": "recipient.email@example.com",
                "vars": [
                    {
                        "name": "merge2",
                        "content": "merge2 content"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "tags": [
            "password-resets"
        ],
        "subaccount": "customer-123",
        "google_analytics_domains": [
            "example.com"
        ],
        "google_analytics_campaign": "message.from_email@example.com",
        "metadata": {
            "website": "www.example.com"
        },
        "recipient_metadata": [
            {
                "rcpt": "recipient.email@example.com",
                "values": {
                    "user_id": 123456
                }
            }
        ],
        "attachments": [
            {
                "type": "text/plain",
                "name": "myfile.txt",
                "content": "ZXhhbXBsZSBmaWxl"
            }
        ],
        "images": [
            {
                "type": "image/png",
                "name": "IMAGECID",
                "content": "ZXhhbXBsZSBmaWxl"
            }
        ]
    },
    "async": false,
    "ip_pool": "Main Pool",
    "send_at": "example send_at"
}
```

I looked at the other questions of sending HTTP Post using Jersey and all I could find was a way to only send a `key\value` pairs as parameters and not complex string types like above.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at JAXB, it allows you to "automatically" build "complex parameters" out of "objects". Basically the procedure would be to define a class that represents the data structure you present as request message the REST API resource accepts, then populate it with the data your want to POST and send it. In this question you can find more details on how to exactly do that: [Can jersey clients POST a JAXB object to the server using JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18665617/can-jersey-clients-post-a-jaxb-object-to-the-server-using-json?rq=1)